# BigQuery Duplicate column names

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query:

```
WITH DAY_WIDGET_STAT AS (
SELECT hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, hits.eventInfo.eventAction, hits.eventInfo.eventLabel, hits.page.pagePath  
FROM `api-open-broker.108613784.ga_sessions_20181125`, UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE hits.type='EVENT' and hits.eventInfo.eventCategory LIKE "%Widget%"
),
DAY_PAGEVIEWS_STAT AS (
SELECT hits.page.pagePath, COUNT(*) AS pageviews
FROM `api-open-broker.108613784.ga_sessions_20181125`,UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE hits.type = 'PAGE' GROUP BY hits.page.pagePath ORDER BY pageviews DESC)

SELECT * 
FROM DAY_WIDGET_STAT INNER JOIN DAY_PAGEVIEWS_STAT ON DAY_WIDGET_STAT.pagePath=DAY_PAGEVIEWS_STAT.pagePath
LIMIT 10
```

Which gives me "Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): pagePath".
Why?
Table DAY_WIDGET_STAT:
[Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dEZi.png)
DAY_PAGEVIEWS_STAT:
[Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMwHj.png)

Answer (score 15):

The duplicate is `pagePath`; this is in both the CTEs.  In this case, I would probably recommend:

```
SELECT w.*,
       p.* EXCEPT (pagePath) 
FROM DAY_WIDGET_STAT w INNER JOIN
     DAY_PAGEVIEWS_STAT p
     ON w.pagePath = p.pagePath
LIMIT 10;
```

Alternatively, `USING` should also do what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DAY_WIDGET_STAT w INNER JOIN
     DAY_PAGEVIEWS_STAT p
     USING (pagePath)
LIMIT 10;
```

You might be able to rewrite the query to be a single aggregation, but without sample data and desired results, it is a little hard to figure out.  If you are interested, you can ask another question.